# dbx WUA error tracing in code

Tags: c, memory-leaks, oracle11g, dbx

I am debugging a program for memory leaks. I am getting following error when "check -memuse" is enabled:

```
Write to unallocated (wua) on thread 1:
Attempting to write 8 bytes at address 0xffffffff79f001d0
t@1 (l@1) stopped in _private_pthread_atfork at 0xffffffff5bd4ce28
```

When I issue Where command:

```
current thread: t@1
=>[1] _private_pthread_atfork(0xffffffff64d565ac, 0xffffffff64d5660c, 0xffffffff64d565dc, 0xffffffff79f001c0, 0xffffffff64eb6a50, 0xffffffff5bf4a360), at 0xffffffff5bd4ce28
  [2] _init(0x0, 0x0, 0xffffffff7f73cdf8, 0xffffffff7f617c5c, 0xffffffff5bdd6908, 0xffffffff6a700200), at 0xffffffff64d9e2d8
  [3] call_init(0xffffffff79d02670, 0x1, 0x10020204, 0xffffffff64d9e2d0, 0x80, 0xffffffff77e01d18), at 0xffffffff7f617c64
  [4] setup(0x21441, 0xffffffff7f73c278, 0xffffffff7f73c4a4, 0x25000, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xffffffff7f616f50
  [5] _setup(0xffffffff7f638f8c, 0x1401c0, 0x0, 0xffffffff7ffff578, 0x2, 0xffffffffffffffff), at 0xffffffff7f6297f4
  [6] _rt_boot(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xffffffff7f608028
```

Can I trace it back where in code where this error is occurred? Can you please give little help to trace back to source ?

> ### More Information

This is a proC process. When compiled on 10g it works fine. Provided binary is loading Oracle 10g libraries.
But When compiled with 11g with gives error. During my debugging I found following memory leaks on 10g at following code:

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT :Userid;
oraca.orastxtf = ORASTFANY;

(dbx) showleaks
Checking for memory leaks...

Actual leaks report    (actual leaks:            1  total size:       1112 bytes)

  Total     Num of  Leaked     Allocation call stack
  Size      Blocks  Block
                    Address
==========  ====== =========== =======================================
      1112       1 0x1003231c8  _nss_XbyY_buf_alloc < get_pwbuf < _getpwuid < sigunmu < kpueaudi < kpugskey < kpu8lgn < kpuauthxa


Possible leaks report  (possible leaks:          0  total size:          0 bytes)
```

During debugging at 11g to same code I got following memory leaks:

```
(dbx) showleaks
Checking for memory leaks...

Actual leaks report    (actual leaks:            4  total size:      25816 bytes)

  Total     Num of  Leaked     Allocation call stack
  Size      Blocks  Block
                    Address
==========  ====== =========== =======================================
     16384       1 0x1002c9b88  calloc < slts_tls_getaddr < sltsqKeyAdd < sltskys < dbgc_tls_ini < dbgc_find_diagctx < kpeDbgInitDBGC < nlstddt_do_alter_trace
      8280       1 0x1002c7b08  calloc < slts_tls_getaddr < sltsqKeyAdd < sltskys < dbgc_tls_ini < dbgc_find_diagctx < kpeDbgInitDBGC < nlstddt_do_alter_trace
      1112       1 0x10038b7e8  _nss_XbyY_buf_alloc < get_pwbuf < _getpwuid < sigunmu < siugunmu < kpugskey < kpu8lgn < kpuauthxa
        40       1 0x10028f658  sltsqKeyAdd < sltskys < dbgc_tls_ini < dbgc_find_diagctx < kpeDbgInitDBGC < nlstddt_do_alter_trace < nlstdggo < nlstdgg
```

Can anyone have such issue ?

Comment: Thanks Joachim for your reply. Basically it is a Pro*C process. And when it comes to execute SQL on server it give error that some in program memory is being leaked. After this if you feel that Oracle should be removed then I will do that.

Comment: Did you compile your program for debug?

Comment: Klas thanks for reply. Yes I have compiled it for debug. Can you please share parameter for CC debug mode compilation so that I can confirm.

Comment: Dears more information added make this will give idea about problem.

Answer (score 1):

The WUA error is bogus. There was a bug filed against RTC:
     7014457 RTC reports a false positive in _pthread_atfork

This bug has been fixed in dbx7.9. Oracle Studio has a new code analyzer tool that can detect memory leak errors as wells as other static and dynamic issues. You may find more discussion about these tools in https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=894